# Polymophism in C#, how to turn parent object into a child object in a method?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, .net-core

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var type = new C().getType();
        type.Foo();
    }

    public class A 
    {
        public void Stop() 
        {
           // do something
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public void Foo() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");   
        }
    }

    public class D : A
    {
        public void Bar() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");   
        }
    }   

    public class C
    {
        public A getType()
        {
            if (some condition)
               return new B();
            if (some condition)
               return new D();
            return A();
        }   
    }
}
```

**-EDIT-**

I updated the code, so now we have two child classes `B` and `D`, both have different methods inside them, however since they inherit `A`, they at least both have access to `Stop()` method. The problem with making an abstract method `Foo()` and `Bar()` inside the parent class `A` is that, `B` should not have access to `Bar()` and `D` should not have access to `Foo()`, but by making an abstract method they will need to implement them both.

I know that I can check the type of the returned object inside `Main()` method and then cast it to that type. But this won't be convenient as in the future I will have more descendants of `A`.

Is it in my situation ok, to use `dynamic`? Because that would solve the problem and would be very convenient.

```
public class C
{
    public dynamic getType()
    {
        if (some condition)
           return new B();
        if (some condition)
           return new D();
        return A();
    }   
}
```

Comment: "in the future I will have more child classes." - since we have no idea what these other classes will look like, and everything is so abstract currently, it's difficult to know what you're looking for. For example, will `getType` be deciding which of those classes to return with some logic? If so, what is/isn't common between the classes it'll select between?

Comment: @OS Are you able to define object of which type (`B` or `D`) you get when you cal `new C().getType()`? How does method `C.getType()` define object of which type to create?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev `C.getType()` does it based on condition in the `if` statements, however in the `Main()` method it has currently no way of knowing what child type is being returned so it using `A` instead. I need a way in the `Main()` to find out what type of child object `C.getType()` returned.

Comment: @OS Under such conditions I think that a possible solution is to check type of the returned object, cast it to that type and then use it. But if you are going to create a lot of descendants of `A` such solution will not be convenient.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I'm indeed going to create many descendants of `A` and that is the problem right now, that type checking isn't convenient at all.

Comment: I could, of course, use `dynamic` keyword to solve my problem, only I'm unsure if this right thing to do, it sure is the most convenient way.

Comment: @OS If you use dynamic than you could get an error if you try to call a method that does not exist in the returned object. In the provided code you will get an error if you call `type.Bar();`.

Comment: It's a design problem. Using `dynamic` will make it worse. If only B is to have a method `Foo` and in main you want to call `Foo` you _must_ already know that the object needs to be a B. If on the other hand, you do not really care, you just want `Foo` to be executed _if_ `type` is of type `B`, then you could give `A` a virtual method `Foo` that simply does nothing. (Think "Adapter Pattern")

Comment: Read more about upcasting and downcasting [Upcast And Downcast Basics](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upcast-and-downcast-basics)

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it right:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var type = new C().getType();
        type.Foo();
    }

    public abstract class A 
    {
        public abstract void Foo();
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override void Foo() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");   
        }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public A getType()
        {
            return new B(); 
        }   
    }
}
```

You need a Foo method in A that B can override. I have made A.Foo abstract, which means we do not have to define a base implementation of A.Foo.  The A class is declared abstract to prevent someone trying to create an instance of it.

If you want derived classes to inherit a base implementation of Foo from A, then declare Foo as virtual in A. So in the following example, class B overrides the base Foo, whereas class C inherits the base Foo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a1 = new B();
        a1.Foo();  // Outputs "B.Foo".
        A a2 = new C();
        a2.Foo();  // Outputs "A.Foo".
    }

    public abstract class A
    {
        public virtual void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A.Foo");
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B.Foo");
        }
    }

    public class C : A
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies for not being so clear in the main question, I'm really bad at asking questions, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the type of a variable and the type of the runtime object it will be pointing to (given its a reference type, with value types, there is no such distinction).

When you declare a variable, you are defining the type of the *variable*:

```
Foo a = ... //a is of type Foo at compile time.
```

What you assign to that variable doesn't matter at all (unless you are using implicitly typed variables with `var`)

But given the following code:

```
object o = new Foo();
```

Now you can see the diferrence; the variable `o` is of type `object` but the runtime object it will be pointing to is of type `string`.

In your question you are asking why you cant do the following:

```
var stringLength = o.Length; //o is a string isn't it?
```

Why? Isn't `o` really a `string`. Yes, but that information is only availabe *at runtime*, the compiler knows nothing of what will happen at runtime, it only knows that `o` is of type `object` and `object` has no `Length` property. The only thing the compiler will make sure of is that the types are compatible; it will let you assign a `Giraffe` to an `Animal` typed variable but it won't let you assing a `Car`.

If you've got this clear, then you'll understando why this doesn't make sense:

> But I did explicitly return B inside getType() method, why does it not have access to Foo()?

Because the method `getType` return type is `A` not `B`, not `C` and not `D`.